# Set framerate equal to the number of frames in Windows Live Movie Maker

Tags: video-editing, windows-live, framerate, windows-live-movie-maker

I have rendered exactly 60 frames in a 3D animation tool.

Now I want to create a 2 second 30 FPS movie using those 60 frames.

How do I accomplish this in Windows Live Movie Maker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the time for each frame to a fraction like 0.6666666666667 or whatever and the program automatically rounded the length of the entire movie in seconds to an integer. I guess I got lucky!